# React TypeScript document.getElementById always selects the first instance

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I've got 2 of the same components being rendered

```
<div><Modal title='Join'/></div>
<div><Modal title='Login'/></div>
```

the modal components is like this

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import {Join} from './join';
import {Login} from './login';

interface propsInterface {
    title: string; 
}

const Modal: React.FC<propsInterface> = (props) => {
  const [state, setState] = useState({showLogin: props.title === "login" ? false : true}); 
  let modalState = false;

  function toggleLogin(event: any) {
    setState({...state, showLogin: !state.showLogin});
  }
  function toggleModal(event: any) {
    if (event.target.id !== 'modal') return;
    modalState = !modalState;
    const modal = document.getElementById('modal'); <<==this always selects the first one
    const card = document.getElementById('card'); <<==this always selects the first one
    if (modal && card && modalState === true) {
      modal.style.display = "flex";
      modal.animate([{backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)'}, {backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6)'}], {duration: 200, easing: 'ease-in-out', fill: 'forwards'});
      card.animate([{opacity: 0}, {opacity: 1}], {duration: 200, easing: 'ease-in-out', fill: 'forwards'});
      card.animate([{transform: 'translateY(-200px)'}, {transform: 'translateY(0)'}], {duration: 200, easing: 'ease-in-out', fill: 'forwards'});
    }
    if (modal && card && modalState === false) {
      modal.animate([{backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6)'}, {backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)'}], {duration: 200, easing: 'ease-in-out', fill: 'forwards'});
      card.animate([{opacity: 1}, {opacity: 0}],{duration: 200, easing: 'ease-in-out', fill: 'forwards'});
      card.animate([{transform: 'translateY(0)'}, {transform: 'translateY(-200px)'}], {duration: 200, easing: 'ease-in-out', fill: 'forwards'});
      setTimeout(() => modal.style.display = "none", 200);
    }
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <div className='modal' id='modal' onClick={toggleModal}>
        <div className='card' id='card'>
          {props.title}
        {state.showLogin 
        ? <Login toggleLogin={toggleLogin} toggleModal={toggleModal}/> 
        : <Join toggleLogin={toggleLogin} toggleModal={toggleModal}/>}
        </div>
      </div>
      <div onClick={toggleModal} className='modal-title' id='modal'> {props.title}</div>
    </div>
  );
}

export {Modal};
```

Because there are 2 of this component now in the dom when I use

```
const modal = document.getElementById('modal');
```

the first instance of the component works as expected but the second instance is selecting the first instance not the second instance.

Is there a way to getElementById but only in this component?

Comment: You should look into `ReactDOM.createProtal` for modals... https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html... The answer below is correct you can not have two elements with the same id...

Comment: ids should be unique. However if you use `document.querySelectorAll('#modal')` you *might* get all of them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of setting the Id as 'modal', you can pass id of your field as props and then set its id attribute.Then use getElementById for them.

Your can do like this:

```
<Modal title='Join'  UniqId="modal1"/>
<Modal title='Login' UniqId="modal2"/>
```

Then in your component, you can do something like this:

```
<div className='modal' id={props.UniqId} onClick={toggleModal}>
```

After that, in your JS file, you can use this id:

```
const modal1 = document.getElementById('modal1');
const modal2 = document.getElementById('modal2');
```

Comment: how to concat the props into the id? <div className='modal' id='modal{props.title}' onClick={toggleModal}>

Comment: it looks great i just need to know how to combine a string and a prop to make a unique id like `id='modal{props.title}' `

Comment: if it resolves your problem, then please accept this as answer :)

Comment: `{'string' + this.props.data.imageUrl}` is how to concat a string and a prop incase anyone else was wondering

Answer (score 1):

You should only ever have one element with a given id in the same page, in your case you may want to use classes and use `document.getElementsByClassName("classname")` which is going to return an array of elements with the given class name.

Hope this helps

Comment: even if I change to classes then i will still have two of them being rendered as im reusing the same component twice

Comment: I guess you may try using a ref for that see this link https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

Answer (score 0):

The way that you are doing it looks like you are still using the mindset of using vanilla JavaScript to manipulate DOM elements after events.

Generally in the React world, you should be linking everything into your `render()` methods which are raised every time the state or the properties change within a react component.

So what I would do in your situation is remove all your code which is grabbing DOM elements, e.g. your `document.getElementById` code, and purely work from your state change. I am sorry that this won't be complete code, as I am not sure what your UI is supposed to look like.

```
const Modal: React.FC<propsInterface> = (props) => {

    const [state, setState] = useState({ showLogin: props.title === "login" ? false : true, showModal: false, showCard: false }); 

    function toggleLogin() {
        setState({ showLogin: !state.showLogin });
    }

    function toggleModal() {
        setState({ showModal: !state.showModal, showCard: !state.showCard });
    }

    const modalClassName = state.showModal ? 'modal show' : 'modal';
    const cardClassName = state.showLogin ? 'card show' : 'card';

    return (
      <div>
        <div className={modalClassName} onClick={toggleModal}>
          <div className={cardClassName}>
            {props.title}
          {state.showLogin 
          ? <Login toggleLogin={toggleLogin} toggleModal={toggleModal}/> 
          : <Join toggleLogin={toggleLogin} toggleModal={toggleModal}/>}
          </div>
        </div>
        <div onClick={toggleModal} className='modal-title' id='modal'> {props.title}</div>
      </div>
    );
}
```

Effectively what happens is that when the `toggleModal` method is called, it just toggles the two state properties between true/false. This causes the component to re-render, and the class names change on the `div` elements.

From this, you will need to move all your animations into your css file and probably make use of animations in there (css animations are not my greatest skill). It's not a simple change to what you have, but I would always keep my styling and animations outside of a component and in a css file, and always work from rendering rather than trying to manipulate react nodes after render.